# Changing SUBQUERY in WHERE clause to NORMAL JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

My new system is not accepting nested/sub queries. I need help in converting below sql to normal join. I tried my approach but result is not same:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
TRAINING.COURSE_SCHEDULE COURSE_SCHEDULE
LEFT JOIN
ENGINE.PHASE_SETTINGS PHASE_SETTINGS ON (COURSE_SCHEDULE.ETQ$CURRENT_PHASE = PHASE_SETTINGS.PHASE_ID)
LEFT JOIN
TRAINING.COURSE_PROFILE AS COURSE_PROFILE ON (COURSE_SCHEDULE.COURSE_PROFILE = COURSE_PROFILE.COURSE_PROFILE_ID)
LEFT JOIN
TRAINING.ETQ$COURSE_SCHEDULE_ASN ETQ$COURSE_SCHEDULE_ASN_1 ON (COURSE_SCHEDULE.COURSE_SCHEDULE_ID = ETQ$COURSE_SCHEDULE_ASN_1.COURSE_SCHEDULE_ID)
LEFT JOIN
ENGINE.USER_SETTINGS USER_SETTINGS_1 ON (ETQ$COURSE_SCHEDULE_ASN_1.ETQ$ASSIGNED = USER_SETTINGS_1.USER_ID)
LEFT JOIN
ENGINE.BOOLEAN_VALUES BOOLEAN_VALUES_1 ON (COURSE_SCHEDULE.TEST_IS_REQUIRED = BOOLEAN_VALUES_1.VALUE)
WHERE
PHASE_SETTINGS.PHASE_TYPE IN (5)
AND COURSE_PROFILE.COURSE_PROFILE_ID NOT IN


(SELECT COURSE_PROFILE.COURSE_PROFILE_ID
FROM TRAINING.COURSE_PROFILE COURSE_PROFILE
LEFT JOIN
TRAINING.ETQ$COURSE_PROFILE_TTL TEST_TEMPLATE_LINK ON (COURSE_PROFILE.COURSE_PROFILE_ID = TEST_TEMPLATE_LINK.COURSE_PROFILE_ID)
LEFT JOIN
TRAINING.ETQ$DOCUMENT_LINKS DOCUMENT_LINKS ON (TEST_TEMPLATE_LINK.TEST_TEMPLATE_ID = DOCUMENT_LINKS.LINK_ID)
LEFT JOIN
TRAINING.TEST_TEMPLATE ON (DOCUMENT_LINKS.DOCUMENT_ID = TEST_TEMPLATE.TEST_TEMPLATE_ID)
LEFT JOIN
TRAINING.TEST_DOCUMENT TEST_DOCUMENT ON (TEST_TEMPLATE.TEST_TEMPLATE_ID = TEST_DOCUMENT.TEST_TEMPLATE)
WHERE TEST_DOCUMENT_DATE IS NULL)
```

Comment: When you say "My new system is not accepting nested/sub queries" what does this mean? Do you get an error? Or is this a political rather than technical problem?

Comment: Also, it's pretty hard for us to rewrite other people's queries as we don't understand the business rules, the data, the access paths.

Comment: Is this Oracle or MySQL? They aren't the same, and the syntax is different. Please tag correctly

Comment: What table does **test_document_date** belong to? i.e. within the subquery you use `WHERE test_document_date IS NULL` but there is nothing to indicate which table it belongs to. You can try changing the where clause to use NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN

Comment: Hold your horses please. It's more of a political situation :)
I'm not asking to rewrite, just give me a way so that I can work.

Comment: It's MYSQL but what difference does that make while joining tables.

Comment: When I said 'Not supporting nested', I meant it's not taking two select statement in same query.

Answer (score 0):

Does `With` clause counts as nested?

```
WITH UNWANTED AS(
    SELECT COURSE_PROFILE.COURSE_PROFILE_ID
    FROM TRAINING.COURSE_PROFILE COURSE_PROFILE
    LEFT JOIN TRAINING.ETQ$COURSE_PROFILE_TTL TEST_TEMPLATE_LINK ON (COURSE_PROFILE.COURSE_PROFILE_ID = TEST_TEMPLATE_LINK.COURSE_PROFILE_ID)
    LEFT JOIN TRAINING.ETQ$DOCUMENT_LINKS DOCUMENT_LINKS ON (TEST_TEMPLATE_LINK.TEST_TEMPLATE_ID = DOCUMENT_LINKS.LINK_ID)
    LEFT JOIN TRAINING.TEST_TEMPLATE ON (DOCUMENT_LINKS.DOCUMENT_ID = TEST_TEMPLATE.TEST_TEMPLATE_ID)
    LEFT JOIN TRAINING.TEST_DOCUMENT TEST_DOCUMENT ON (TEST_TEMPLATE.TEST_TEMPLATE_ID = TEST_DOCUMENT.TEST_TEMPLATE)
    WHERE TEST_DOCUMENT_DATE IS NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM TRAINING.COURSE_SCHEDULE COURSE_SCHEDULE
LEFT JOIN ENGINE.PHASE_SETTINGS PHASE_SETTINGS ON (COURSE_SCHEDULE.ETQ$CURRENT_PHASE = PHASE_SETTINGS.PHASE_ID)
LEFT JOIN TRAINING.COURSE_PROFILE AS COURSE_PROFILE ON (COURSE_SCHEDULE.COURSE_PROFILE = COURSE_PROFILE.COURSE_PROFILE_ID)
LEFT JOIN TRAINING.ETQ$COURSE_SCHEDULE_ASN ETQ$COURSE_SCHEDULE_ASN_1 ON (COURSE_SCHEDULE.COURSE_SCHEDULE_ID = ETQ$COURSE_SCHEDULE_ASN_1.COURSE_SCHEDULE_ID)
LEFT JOIN ENGINE.USER_SETTINGS USER_SETTINGS_1 ON (ETQ$COURSE_SCHEDULE_ASN_1.ETQ$ASSIGNED = USER_SETTINGS_1.USER_ID)
LEFT JOIN ENGINE.BOOLEAN_VALUES BOOLEAN_VALUES_1 ON (COURSE_SCHEDULE.TEST_IS_REQUIRED = BOOLEAN_VALUES_1.VALUE)
LEFT JOIN UNWANTED UNW on UNW.COURSE_PROFILE_ID = COURSE_PROFILE.COURSE_PROFILE_ID
WHERE PHASE_SETTINGS.PHASE_TYPE IN (5)
AND UNW.COURSE_PROFILE_ID IS NULL;
```

I understand `WITH` is a work around option for nested sub queries, I'm sorry if this is of no help in your painful limitation.

UPDATE:

OK let's try this way, basically applies the same logic as above, but with sub query now integrated with your main `SELECT`, which I believe is what you were looking for in the first place:

```
SELECT *
FROM TRAINING.COURSE_SCHEDULE AS COURSE_SCHEDULE
LEFT JOIN ENGINE.PHASE_SETTINGS AS PHASE_SETTINGS ON (COURSE_SCHEDULE.ETQ$CURRENT_PHASE = PHASE_SETTINGS.PHASE_ID)
LEFT JOIN TRAINING.COURSE_PROFILE AS COURSE_PROFILE ON (COURSE_SCHEDULE.COURSE_PROFILE = COURSE_PROFILE.COURSE_PROFILE_ID)
LEFT JOIN TRAINING.ETQ$COURSE_SCHEDULE_ASN AS ETQ$COURSE_SCHEDULE_ASN_1 ON (COURSE_SCHEDULE.COURSE_SCHEDULE_ID = ETQ$COURSE_SCHEDULE_ASN_1.COURSE_SCHEDULE_ID)
LEFT JOIN ENGINE.USER_SETTINGS AS USER_SETTINGS_1 ON (ETQ$COURSE_SCHEDULE_ASN_1.ETQ$ASSIGNED = USER_SETTINGS_1.USER_ID)
LEFT JOIN ENGINE.BOOLEAN_VALUES AS BOOLEAN_VALUES_1 ON (COURSE_SCHEDULE.TEST_IS_REQUIRED = BOOLEAN_VALUES_1.VALUE)
LEFT JOIN TRAINING.COURSE_PROFILE AS COURSE_PROFILE_2 ON COURSE_PROFILE_2.COURSE_PROFILE_ID = COURSE_PROFILE.COURSE_PROFILE_ID
LEFT JOIN TRAINING.ETQ$COURSE_PROFILE_TTL AS TEST_TEMPLATE_LINK ON (COURSE_PROFILE_2.COURSE_PROFILE_ID = TEST_TEMPLATE_LINK.COURSE_PROFILE_ID)
LEFT JOIN TRAINING.ETQ$DOCUMENT_LINKS AS DOCUMENT_LINKS ON (TEST_TEMPLATE_LINK.TEST_TEMPLATE_ID = DOCUMENT_LINKS.LINK_ID)
LEFT JOIN TRAINING.TEST_TEMPLATE ON (DOCUMENT_LINKS.DOCUMENT_ID = TEST_TEMPLATE.TEST_TEMPLATE_ID)
LEFT JOIN TRAINING.TEST_DOCUMENT AS TEST_DOCUMENT ON (TEST_TEMPLATE.TEST_TEMPLATE_ID = TEST_DOCUMENT.TEST_TEMPLATE
                                                      AND TEST_DOCUMENT.TEST_DOCUMENT_DATE IS NULL)
WHERE PHASE_SETTINGS.PHASE_TYPE IN (5)
AND COURSE_PROFILE_2.COURSE_PROFILE_ID IS NULL;
```

Note that I changed the alias for `COURSE_PROFILE` from the original nested query to `COURSE_PROFILE_2` so it does not conflict with `COURSE_PROFILE` from the main query, and since column `TEST_DOCUMENT_DATE` from the original sub query didn't had a table alias attached, I inferred from it's name it belonged to the `TEST_DOCUMENT` table, change it if this is wrong. Good luck.

Comment: That's actually excellent. please give me a while to try this  :)

Comment: Unfortunately same error as two SELECT statement in same SQL denied, thanks again for checking it

Comment: OK no problem, I've updated my answer to try with a new approach, check it out if you please.

Comment: Thanks again...
Why did you add ID as NULL at the end?
AND COURSE_PROFILE_2.COURSE_PROFILE_ID IS NULL

Comment: In the original query, you wanted all the `COURSE_PROFILE_ID` that were `NOT IN` the `COURSE_PROFILE_ID`'s   returned by the sub query. Well with this approach, all the `LEFT JOINED`  tables established by the sub query, now integrated into the main one, will give you all the rows that match the `COURSE_PROFILE_ID` but also the ones that don't, that's where the `COURSE_PROFILE_2.COURSE_PROFILE_ID IS NULL` comes in, all the ID's that appear as `NULL` are the ones that don't exist within the sub query logic, and hence ruling those rows out will deliver the same result as in the original `NOT IN`

Comment: Sorry I meant "ruling those IN" not out... because the ones that are null comply with the `NOT IN` for the sub query logic.